# What is the worst case running time to search for an element in a balanced binary search tree with n*2^n elements?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I know that searching a balanced tree with n nodes is O(logN)，but I don't even know why the tree the question states is also a balanced BST.

Comment: It's specified as a balanced BST rather than just a balanced tree because searching for an item in a binary tree that is not ordered is an O(n) operation, even if the tree is balanced.

Comment: Why is searching a binary tree O(n) even if it is balanced. And I'm somehow confused about BST and binary tree

Comment: A Binary Search Tree is constructed with an order. Given a node, anything less than the value of that node is to the left, and anything greater or equal is to the right. That's not true of binary tree in general. So if you can't guarantee that the tree is ordered, then a search will be O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you said, a balanced BST with k has a lookup time of O(log k). So all we have to do is plug in n2<sup>n</sup> for k to see what we get:

> log (n2<sup>n</sup>)
>
> = log n + log 2<sup>n</sup>
>
> = log n + n log 2
>
> = O(n).

And that makes sense, since a tree with exponentially many nodes in it hit with a logarithmic-time algorithm ought to take linear time.